# row is not inserting into table

Tags: database, oracle

The table is present in oracle database, I am updating that table with one record. It's executing and when I type `select *` from that table it's showing that record.

But the problem is when I commit the changes. The table is showing nothing - I am not seeing anythng inside table, it's showing 0 records.

Can you please help me?

```
insert into recon values(1,'sri',-1,'20090806');
```

after this if i write

```
select * from recon;
```

It's showing that record but after commit it's showing nothing. There is no trigger for that table.

its not a view.

Comment: Check if there is a trigger on the table - also, please post a log of your SQL commands to help us analyze the problem.

Comment: Please post the SQL statements you are running.

Comment: insert into recon values(1,'sri',-1,'20090806');

after this if i write

select * from recon;
its showing that record

but after commit its showing nothing.

there is no trigger for that table

Comment: so just to be sure, please do this in the same session: insert into recon values(1,'sri',-1,'20090806'); commit; select * from recon;

Comment: ya i have done this also .same problem no rows selected after commit.

Comment: Are you sure that `recon` is a table and not a view?

Comment: From what type of environment are you issuing the commands, e.g. SQL*Plus, Toad, etc?

Comment: well, that's good - eliminates IDE side effects.  Taking your results at face value, the only thing I can think of would be to enable auditing on the table to see if there is another process somewhere that is deleting the row after you insert it.  Do you have the necessary privileges to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a global temporary table, after commiting it is emptied.

There are two kind of temp tables, 1 after commit emptied, 2.after ending session emptied.

Comment: Definitely a possibility.  To verify, `SELECT temporary FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'recon'`.  If this is 'Y' then it is a global temporary table.  I'm not sure how to verify whether it is set to delete on commit, but it would certainly explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: where table_name = 'recon' -> where table_name = 'RECON'

Comment: @musicking123 - did it turn out that this was a temp table?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the transaction was not committed properly, initially I thought that it was because of nested transactions (I work in SQLServer) but could be basically because of not properly committed transaction

Comment: am commiting it afre inserting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the admin, Check if other users are logged into the the database and are using that table, unlock the user from that table/database.

Comment: how to check if other users are accessing tha same database/table?

Comment: Check out this link http://www.shutdownabort.com/dbaqueries/Performance_Locks_DML.php#Show-locked-objects